# error installing helm chart in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I am trying to install helm chart on kubernetes cluster. When i try to initialize the helm using init command, it is throwing error as `"error installing: the server could not find the requested resource"`

provider.helm v2.14.3

provider.kubernetes v1.16

```bash
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:27:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```bash
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find tiller
```

```bash
$ helm init
Creating /home/cloud_admin/.helm
Creating /home/cloud_admin/.helm/repository
Creating /home/cloud_admin/.helm/repository/cache
Creating /home/cloud_admin/.helm/repository/local
Creating /home/cloud_admin/.helm/plugins
Creating /home/cloud_admin/.helm/starters
Creating /home/cloud_admin/.helm/cache/archive
Creating /home/cloud_admin/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/cloud_admin/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource
```

```bash
$ kubectl get node -n kube-system
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
openamvmimsload0   Ready    master   5h11m   v1.16.0
openamvmimsload1   Ready    <none>   5h1m    v1.16.0
```

```bash
$ kubectl config get-clusters
NAME
kubernetes
```

```bash
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://172.16.128.40:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://172.16.128.40:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

```bash
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   5h15m
```

Comment: Did you follow the recommendation from the command output? What `kubectl cluster-info dump` returns?

Comment: @Yasen I followed the steps as the helm documentation. I am using kubeadm to build the kubernetes cluster. Here is few line from the cluster-info logs. E0924 10:07:48.809416       1 reflector.go:280] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Service: Get https://172.16.128.40:6443/api/v1/services?allowWatchBookmarks=true&labelSelector=%21service.kubernetes.io%2Fheadless%2C%21service.kubernetes.io%2Fservice-proxy-name&resourceVersion=175&timeout=8m52s&timeoutSeconds=532&watch=true: dial tcp 172.16.128.40:6443: connect: connection refused

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with Helm 2.14.3 (and previous) and Kubernetes 1.16 [Helm init fails on Kubernetes 1.16.0 bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6374).

The ticket lists some workarounds - the simplest one is:

```
helm init --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -
```

or with RBAC enabled and `tiller` service account:

```
helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Please accept the answer when the solution is working (and optionally add additional information)

Answer (score 1):

it will work if you use this command:

````
helm init --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -```
````